# Gray out non-business hours in jQuery week calendar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins

I am using the [jQuery weekcalendar plugin](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar) to show a web based calendar with events. How can I gray out non-business hours? The whole row should be gray, when it is out of the business hours:

```
businessHours: {start: 8, end: 19, limitDisplay: false},
```

Comment: Are you saying that product has a parameter named `businessHours` and it is not working? Or that you would like to have such a parameter?

Comment: No the parameter is existing and is set. Now I just want to gray out the non-business hours with CSS.

Comment: I see. I guess the easiest way would be to use the "Inspect element" feature in your browser to see what classes the business/non-business hours have set, and then to address those classes using CSS. Do they have classes set? Or some other feature that helps tell them apart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Incomplete answer. It doesn't highlight the whole row.

Thanks to Phekka I found this in the Inspect element section:

Non-Business-Hours:

```
<div class="wc-hour-header ui-state-default"></div>
```

Business-Hours:

```
<div class="wc-hour-header ui-state-active wc-business-hours"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use global variables for your business hours like so:

```
var timeStart = 8
var timeEnd = 19

businessHours: {start: timeStart , end: timeEnd , limitDisplay: false},
```

Then, try adding this to the jquery javascript on document ready (after the calendar is created):

```
$('.wc-time-slot').each(function(index, element) {
    if (index<6*timeStart||index>=6*timeEnd) {
        $(this).css('background-color','#eee')
    }
});
```

There are six rows per hour so that's why you're multiplying by 6.

Comment: Genius! Thank you. The bounty is blocked for the next 11h. I will award it when it is not blocked anymore!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit hard. I think you have to manage with 
`td.wc-day-column` background properties and add a [css3 gradient](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) with **calculated pixel or percent** value.

Good luck.